# How to change button text javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a javascript button created dynamically into a dynamically created table, I want the button to toggle "read/not read" on click but it only changes from one to the other only after a refresh and it does it once, so for example i have a book and i click the status it goes from "read" to "not read" but when i click again it does not react or when i click another book in the table.

```js
let books = [];

const $name = document.querySelector("#name");
const $author = document.querySelector("#author");
const $status = document.querySelector("#status");
const $pages = document.querySelector("#pages"); 
const $tableBody = document.querySelector("#book-table-body");


function addBookToTable() {
    // checkLocalStorage();
    $tableBody.innerHTML = "";
    books.forEach((book) => {
      const htmlBook = `
        <tr>
          <td>${book.title}</td>
          <td>${book.author}</td>
          <td>${book.pages}</td>
          <td><button class="status-button">${book.status}</button></td>
          <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        `;
      $tableBody.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", htmlBook);
    });
  }

const addBook = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let book = {
        title: $("#title").val(),
        author: $("#author").val(),
        pages: $("#pages").val(),
        status: $("#status").val(),
    };
    const cb = document.querySelector("#status");

    if (cb.checked === true) {
        book.status = "read";
    } else {
        book.status = "not read";
    }
    books.push(book);
    document.forms[0].reset();
    // Update DOM
    addBookToTable(book);

    const deleteBtn = document.querySelector(".delete");
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function deleteBook(){
        books.splice(books.indexOf(book), 1);
        console.log(books);
    })

    const myBtn = document.querySelector(".status-button");
    myBtn.addEventListener('click', function changeStatus(){
        if (book.status === "read"){
            myBtn.innerHTML="not read"
        } 
        else if(book.status === "not read"){
            myBtn.innerHTML = "read";
        }
    }
    );

    localStorage.setItem("myMangaList", JSON.stringify(books));
};

function popForm() {
    $("#popup").removeClass("hide");
}

function minimizeForm(){
    $("#popup").addClass("hide");
}

function hideForm() {
    $("#popup").addClass("hide");
    $("#main-page").removeClass("hide");
}

function toggle() {
    $("#main-page").addClass("hide");

}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  /* background-image: url(./images/image.jpg);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover; */
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.hide-form {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 span {
  color: #48abe0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  /* border: 1px solid #dddddd; */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}


#main-page {
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-left: 80px;

}

#addBook {
  border-radius: 70%;
  background-color: #48abe0;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 31px;
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px darkslategray;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 25px;
}


#popup {
  /* display: flex; */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 30px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  background: #48abe0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#popup input {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #48abe0;

}

.status-box {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Edu+NSW+ACT+Foundation:wght@500&family=Edu+QLD+Beginner:wght@400;600;700&family=Edu+TAS+Beginner:wght@700&family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300&family=Lato&family=Montserrat:wght@100;600&family=Mouse+Memoirs&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,500;1,200&family=Quicksand:wght@300&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&family=Work+Sans:wght@200&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Library</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>My <span>Manga</span> Library</h1>

    <div id="popup" class="hide">
        <form>
            <button class="hide-form" onclick=" minimizeForm()">X</button>
            <!-- <label for="title">Manga Title:</label> -->
            <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title eg: One Piece"> <br>

            <!-- <label for="author">Author:</label> -->
            <input type="text" id="author" placeholder="Author eg: Eichiro Oda"><br>

            <!-- <label for="pages">Pages:</label> -->
            <input type="text" id="pages" placeholder="Pages eg: 2000"><br>

            <div class="status-box">
                <label for="status">Read the book</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="status" name="status" value="">

            </div>


            <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="addBook(event); hideForm()">Submit</button>

        </form>
    </div>


    <!-- onclick="addBook() -->
    <div id="main-page">
        <h1>list</h1>
        <div id="books-grid">
            <table id="di-books">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Pages</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tbody id="book-table-body"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <button id="addBook" onclick="popForm(); toggle()">+</button>

    </div>

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you never change `book.status` ... so ... that's why - it also looks like you'll have duplicate id's - which will break things too

Comment: But I do change it inside the if statement.

Comment: Yes, that statement runs exactly once when the html is created ... why would it run when the status-button button is clicked?

Comment: I don't get it but okay, thanks.

Comment: why would that `if (cb.checked === true) {` run when that button is clicked?

Comment: It can't run cause it only runs when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: `if (cb.checked === true) {` doesn't run when the button is clicked, only the code inside `myBtn.addEventListener('click'` does

Comment: Yes it doesn't, it only runs with the checkbox not with the click.

Comment: that's why clicking `myBtn` does nothing, because the `.status` never changes

Comment: Oh okay, I just finished it. It works now, thank you for the help i almost gave up on the project.